# Rails - Running tests with unexpected results - should be failing but instead its passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing Hartl's tutorial.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages

On section 3.3.3

I am running test but running into unexpected results.

In my `static_pages_controller_test.rb` I have the following:

```
test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
 end
```

According to Listing 3.17, I should be getting:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
The action 'about' could not be found for StaticPagesController
```

However, the test still passes even though there is no `about` action defined in my `static_pages_controller.rb`

gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end
```

Guardfile (though I'm not actively running it to execute test)

```
# Defines the matching rules for Guard.
guard :minitest, spring: true, all_on_start: false do
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)/?(.*)_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { 'test' }
  watch('config/routes.rb')    { integration_tests }
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.*?)\.rb$}) do |matches|
    "test/models/#{matches[1]}_test.rb"
  end
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*?)_controller\.rb$}) do |matches|
    resource_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/([^/]*?)/.*\.html\.erb$}) do |matches|
    ["test/controllers/#{matches[1]}_controller_test.rb"] +
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/helpers/(.*?)_helper\.rb$}) do |matches|
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch('app/views/layouts/application.html.erb') do
    'test/integration/site_layout_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb') do
    integration_tests << 'test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb') do
    ['test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb',
     'test/integration/users_login_test.rb']
  end
  watch('app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb') do
    'test/integration/users_signup_test.rb'
  end
  watch(%r{app/views/users/*}) do
    resource_tests('users') +
    ['test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb']
  end
end

# Returns the integration tests corresponding to the given resource.
def integration_tests(resource = :all)
  if resource == :all
    Dir["test/integration/*"]
  else
    Dir["test/integration/#{resource}_*.rb"]
  end
end

# Returns the controller tests corresponding to the given resource.
def controller_test(resource)
  "test/controllers/#{resource}_controller_test.rb"
end

# Returns all tests for the given resource.
def resource_tests(resource)
  integration_tests(resource) << controller_test(resource)
end
```

Comment: "Only things scarier than when things don't work and they should, is when they work and they shouldn't" ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a view named `about` in static_pages_controller's corresponding view folder?
If so, rails assumes controller action just being empty and proceeds with render.

To have test fail - rename or delete the view

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Note that the sequence in the book adds the `about` template last precisely to avoid this issue.